# spring3 annotation with main method

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have following class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/com/home/app/Home-ctx.xml"})
public class LoginDetailsTest  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoginDetailsTest().testLoginDetails();
    }
    @Inject
    @Named(HomeConstants.loginDetailsService)
    private LoginDetailsService loginDetailsService;
    private List<UserLogin> loginDetails;

    @Test
    public void testLoginDetails() {
        UserLogin login = new UserLogin();
        login.setLoginName("test");
        login.setLoginPassword("test123");
        loginDetails = loginDetailsService.loginDetails(login);
        for (UserLogin loginDet : loginDetails) {
            System.out.println(loginDet.getLoginName());
            System.out.println(loginDet.getLoginPassword());
        }
    }
}
```

if i run above code as junit test, then it gives expected result.
If I run as Java application ie main method, then it gives null pointer exception for 
**loginDetailsService**.loginDetails(login). how can run as main method without error?

Comment: @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
This annotation causes, that dependencies are injected when you run unit tests, but it does not do the same when you run main().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need to do what JUnit does when you "run code as junit test" to bootstrap your application context and dependency injection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(LoginDetailsTest.class);
}
```

Comment: JUnitCore.runClasses(LoginDetailsTest.class); there is no run method in junit4.9.

Comment: This is for running Junit Test and not main method. jeha's answer should be the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

The `main`is a different thing. Because by instantiating the class by `new LoginDetailsTest()` it is not build by Spring - there can be no dependency injection.

What you need to do is:

- make a new application context `appctx.xml` for your `main` method that imports `Home-ctx.xml` and declare a new bean `<bean id="loginDetailsTest" class="LoginDetailsTest"/>`
- in your `main` method get an instance of the bean and call `testLoginDetails()` like this:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appctx.xml");  
      LoginDetailsTest loginDetailsTest = (LoginDetailsTest) context.getBean("loginDetailsTest");
      loginDetailsTest.testLoginDetails();
  }
  ```

In general you should separate the JUnit test, main method and business logic.

Answer (score 1):

First things first the reason your test works is (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner), It does a lot but to keep it simple it boot straps the spring container and injects all the dependencies like that you defined in your context file (Home-ctx.xml) including the one you inject into the test case. For more details look at these classes

1. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/TestContextManager.html
2. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/support/DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.html

To solve the problem with your main method, You have to load the spring context your self and inject the dependency some thing like this

```
 ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/com/home/app/Home-ctx.xml");

 new LoginDetailsTest().loginDetailsService = (LoginDetailsService) ctx.getBean(LoginDetailsService.class); 

 //now your main method should work
 new LoginDetailsTest().testLoginDetails();
```